# Print 2 dimensional array from DB

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, nested

I'm still a new programmer. It's not my day job, but I know enough to be dangerous. I have inserted a nested array into a DB successfully, but I can't figure out how to get it to display properly. This is a list of items ordered in a checkout process.

This is the array echoed out:

```
Array
(
    [products] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [name] => m10x1-5-001 IVB bolt
                    [code] => m10x1-5-001
                    [qty] => 1
                    [price] => 37.00
                    [image] => m10x1-5-001-S.jpg
                    [description] => This is a short description of my item.
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [name] => AA02-015-021 IVB bolt
                    [code] => AA02-015-021
                    [qty] => 1
                    [price] => 39.00
                    [image] => m10x1-5-001-S.jpg
                    [description] => I'm a classic bolt.
                )

        )

)
```

I need to echo this out in readable format, since it's going on an order admin page. It's stored serialized in the 'products' field in mysql, and this is my starter code that isn't working:

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
echo "<table border='1'><tr><th>ID</th><th>header1</th><th>header2:</th><th>Items:</th></tr>";

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $decrypted = decrypt(base64_decode($row["number"]), ENCRYPTION_KEY);
    $decrypted2 = decrypt(base64_decode($row["cvv"]), ENCRYPTION_KEY);

    echo "<tr><td>".$row["id"]."</td><td>".$decrypted."</td><td>".$decrypted2."</td><td>";

   $listitems = base64_decode(unserialize($row["products"]));

        foreach($listitems as $item)
        {
           echo $item['name'] . $item['code'] . $item['qty'] . $item['price'] . $item['image'] . $item['description'] ;
        }


   echo "</td></tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
} else {
echo "0 results";
}
```

I know this code isn't yet referring to the nested nature of the array. Newbie needs a little help.

Comment: How do you want it to be displayed?

Comment: I'll take anything right now. All my code produces is a blank where text should be. The array above is the contents of a shopping cart so I need each item listed.

Comment: Typoheads answer should work for you then.

Comment: I still get nothing. Let me expand the code to view the entire IF statement. Original question modified now.

Answer (score 0):

For a formatted output, you could print a HTML table:

```
$listitems = base64_decode(unserialize($row["products"]));
$output = '<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Code</th>
        <th>Quantity</th>
        <th>Price</th>
        <th>Image</th>
        <th>Description</th>
    </tr>
';

foreach($listitems as $item)
{
    $output .= '<tr>
        <td>' . $item['name'] . '</td>
        <td>' . $item['code'] . '</td>
        <td>' . $item['qty'] . '</td>
        <td>' . $item['price'] . '</td>
        <td>' . $item['image'] . '</td>
        <td>' . $item['description'] . '</td>
    </tr>';
}
$output .= '</table>';
echo $output;
```

Comment: This was perfect. The reason why I couldn't get it to work was because of my mysql field not being long enough to accept the serialized data.